# Laravel busca un archivo que se le cambió el nombre

Tags: laravel

tengo un caso extraño.
Tenia un archivo de DashboardController y antes de hacerle unos cambios le saqué una copia y se generó un DashboardController copy, luego de editar el DashboardController eliminé el "DashboardController copy" pero al ejecutar la aplicación me lanza el error de que no encuentra el "DashboardController copy".
Que puedo hacer??

Comment: En algún lado estás invocando dicho archivo copiado?

Comment: para nada, es un archivo controller, solo llamo a las funciones desde un archivo vue, pero en ningún momento hago una llamada por el nombre del archivo. Es la segunda vez que me pasa, tengo el mismo problema con el archivo LoginController, actualmente lo tengo como "LoginController copy" si lo borro me sale error, a pesar de estar el LoginController original, en ambos casos... tanto el original como el copy tienen el mismo código

Comment: Pareciera ser un asunto de caché de autoloader

Comment: ejecuté los siguientes comandos: php artisan config:cache, php artisan route:cache, php artisan cache:clear y nada funcionó. Volví a cambiarle el nombre al "LoginController cop" por "LoginController" y me volvió a salir el error "ErrorException (E_WARNING)
include(C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController copy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Comment: como limpio el autoloader?

Comment: @Ivan Esto suele pasar al trabajar con composer, lo más probable es que se haya almacenado en el autoload. Para generar el autoload de nuevo puedes utilizar el comando `composer dumpautoload` si aún así sigue fallando revisa que no hayas incluido alguna llamada a ese archivo, utiliza las funciones del editor para buscar en todos los archivos.

Comment: composer dump-autoload, listo. funcionó. muchas gracias